# I need to give variable names to subprocess.call command

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("rm /home/winpc/Desktop/test.html", shell=True)
```

This code working properly.I need to do the following change.

```
file_name="test.html"
dir_path="/home/winpc/Desktop"
```

I need to remove above file test.html using the variables above mentioned.How can I do that.

Comment: If you're using `subprocess.call` I'd recommend you capture the exit code and test for success.

Comment: `shell=True` is actively dangerous -- it means that anyone who can control the name of your file can run arbitrary commands on your system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, construct the full file name properly:

```
full_name = os.path.join(dir_path, file_name)
```

Then, pass a *list* as the first argument to `call`:

```
subprocess.call(["rm", full_name])
```

(In real life, you wouldn't use `call` here at all; you'd use `os.remove(full_name)`.)

Comment: Thank you.Problem solved.I need to perform copy command as folow

Comment: sourse="/home"    dest="/home/test"

Comment: @Kit Open a new question. Actually don't. Just google "how to copy files".

Comment: actually I know how to do that.I need to do that using subprocess command.And I need to pass variables inside to the command.@cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ. All the people do not have born talent to know each an every code and programming language like you guys .I am still learning.A beginner.Please help.

Comment: @Kit It's the same thing: you pass a list whose elements are the name of the command and its arguments: `subprocess.call([cmd_name, arg1, arg2])`.

Comment: @chepner Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: @Kit I meant the question already exists. You'll find it by googling.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string formatting:

```
rm_file = "/home/winpc/Desktop/test.html"
subprocess.call("rm {}".format(rm_file), shell=True)
```

Incidentally I'd recommend not using `shell=True` where possible; instead pass the arguments as a list:

```
rm_file = "/home/winpc/Desktop/test.html"
subprocess.call(["rm", rm_file])
```

Comment: That's more than just a recommendation, but essential for security -- I'd suggest putting the correct/safe/preferred formulation **first** in the answer to make it more prominent. If the user had a file named `/home/winpc/Desktop/$(rm -rf ~).html`...